# Get values from complicated multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
$officeLK = [
    [
        ['text' => "تا ۱ میلیون تومان", 'callback_data' => '111']
    ],
    [
        ['text' => "پانصد هزار تومان", 'callback_data' => '112']
    ],
    [
        ['text' => "۲ میلیون تومان", 'callback_data' => '113']
    ],
    [
        ['text' => "برگشت", 'callback_data' => '1']
    ]
];
```

I need a function to give it the `callback_data` and it return the text value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a foreach loop to iterate through the array and check if the given callback matches.

For example :

```
$officeLK = [
    [
        ['text' => "تا ۱ میلیون تومان", 'callback_data' => '111']
    ],
    [
        ['text' => "پانصد هزار تومان", 'callback_data' => '112']
    ],
    [
        ['text' => "۲ میلیون تومان", 'callback_data' => '113']
    ],
    [
        ['text' => "برگشت", 'callback_data' => '1']
    ]
];

$given_callback = 113:

echo getTextByCallBack($given_callback, $officeLK);

function getTextByCallBack($callback, $officeLK)
{
    foreach ($officeLK as $item) {
        if ($item[0]['callback_data'] == $callback) {
            return $item[0]['text'];
        }
    }
}
```

Will output :

> ۲ میلیون تومان

Comment: I edited my answer to fit to your needs. @SaadatEsmaeily

Comment: @SaadatEsmaeily I re-updated my answer with a function. Hope it helps.

Comment: i'm so sorry. I don't have 15 reputation

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway.